# Difference between "ls -lh" & "ls -lh | tail -n +2"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I was going through the `split` command article on internet and came across this Linux command `ls -lh | tail -n +2` for listing files. Is it any better than `ls -ltrh` (which shows almost the same listing)

Can somebody plz tell me the difference between `ls -lh` & `ls -lh | tail -n +2`

PS: I have checked man pages but still confused

Comment: From `man tail` we see `-n, --lines=K --> output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to output lines starting with the Kth`. So it starts printing from 2nd line.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Linux Shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tail -n +2` skips the first line (total file size).

```
 $ ls -lh
total 79K
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Feb 28 15:05 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 3.0K Feb 28 15:05 boot
drwxr-xr-x  16 root root 4.3K Dec  3 06:43 dev
drwxr-xr-x 112 root root 4.0K Feb 28 15:06 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Aug 29  2012 home

 $ ls -lh | tail -n +2
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Feb 28 15:05 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 3.0K Feb 28 15:05 boot
drwxr-xr-x  16 root root 4.3K Dec  3 06:43 dev
drwxr-xr-x 112 root root 4.0K Feb 28 15:06 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Aug 29  2012 home
```

It is better if there's some further processing that expects just the listing.

`ls -dlh *` will do the same thing.

Comment: Be warned that [processing the output of ls is a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 0):

ls -lh list all content. but ls -lh|tail -n +K, skip the first n - K line from first and list all remaining lines. Like

```
 $ 6:18:39% ls -lh ~/logs
total 264K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vijay    vijay  76K Oct 27 17:13 angular-ui-bootstrap-0.4.0.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vijay    vijay  70K Feb 14 16:52 cloudbash_importdata
-rwxrwxr-x 1 vijay    vijay   86 Feb 14 16:38 findjar.sh
drwxr-xr-x 4 vijay    vijay 4.0K Jun 26  2013 META-INF
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root   87K Feb 28 18:13 nginx_access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root   12K Feb 28 18:13 nginx_error.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vijay    vijay  310 Feb 14 20:19 onlyimport

 $ 6:18:51% ls -lh ~/logs |tail -n +3

-rw-rw-r-- 1 vijay    vijay  70K Feb 14 16:52 cloudbash_importdata
-rwxrwxr-x 1 vijay    vijay   86 Feb 14 16:38 findjar.sh
drwxr-xr-x 4 vijay    vijay 4.0K Jun 26  2013 META-INF
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root   87K Feb 28 18:13 nginx_access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root   12K Feb 28 18:13 nginx_error.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vijay    vijay  310 Feb 14 20:19 onlyimport

 $ 6:19:05% ls -lh ~/logs |tail -n +4

-rwxrwxr-x 1 vijay    vijay   86 Feb 14 16:38 findjar.sh
drwxr-xr-x 4 vijay    vijay 4.0K Jun 26  2013 META-INF
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root   87K Feb 28 18:13 nginx_access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root   12K Feb 28 18:13 nginx_error.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vijay    vijay  310 Feb 14 20:19 onlyimport
```